# Cardinality for all rational strongly increasing sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> What is the cardinality for all rational strongly increasing sequences?

Using diagonalization, I can show easily that for each list $f_n$ of sequnces, we can present a sequence which is not in the list.

Indeed, we can define $$a_k = f_{(k)}(k) + 1$$
The sequence is answering our demand to be strongly increasing yet isn't equal to any existing sequence in our list.

From this we can infer the cardinality is $\ge \aleph_0$.
I know the answer is $\aleph$ but how to show it?

By the way,
If you can show another neat way I'd be glad, **but I do want to complete the diagonaliztion proof**.

Thanks.

Comment: Your $a_k$ is not, in general, strictly increasing. Why should it be? (Also, what do you mean by $\aleph$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $|\mathbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$, because for any real number you can find strictly increasing sequence of rationals converging to it.

It's not more, because it's at most than $|\mathbb Q|^{|\mathbb N|}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Nice argument. Thanks.

Comment: Could you utilize the diagonalization technique here?

Comment: @AnnieOK: I think the diagonalization argument gives you only that it's more than $\aleph_0$, but whether $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the first cardinal after $\aleph_0$ is an unprovable statement known as the Continuum Hypothesis.

Comment: OK. By the way, In which cases would you choose to use diagonaliztion?

Comment: @AnnieOK: I think one example is if you only need to know something is uncountable, not exact cardinality. This is used in the proof that almost all numbers are transcendental.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers, but some people prefer $2^\mathbb{N}$ rather than $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and it is easy in this case (not that it really matters, but perhaps it gives them more intuition, whatever). Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be the set of strongly increasing sequences of rational numbers,
then
$$2^{\mathbb{N}}\ \stackrel{\spadesuit}\leq\ \mathcal{Q}\ \stackrel{\clubsuit} \leq\ 2^{\mathbb{N}}.$$

Injection $f : 2^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathcal{Q}$ can be given, for example, as

$$f(\mathbf{a}) = n \mapsto 2n + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbf{a}_k \tag{$\spadesuit_1$}$$
or
$$f(\mathbf{a}) = n \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^k(1+\mathbf{a}_k).\tag{$\spadesuit_2$}$$

The other direction $g : \mathcal{Q} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$ can be defined by writing rational numbers in unary notation using $1$ as a symbol and $0$ as delimiter, or more formally

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{unary}(p,q) &= (0,\underbrace{1,1}_{\text{two ones if $p \geq 0$}},0,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{|p|+1 \text{ ones}},0,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{q+1 \text{ ones}}) \\
g(\mathbf{b}) &= \mathrm{unary}(\mathbf{b}_0) \star \mathrm{unary}(\mathbf{b}_1) \star \ldots \tag{$\clubsuit$}
\end{align*}

where $\star$ denotes sequence concatenation.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Is $a$ denote a seuqeunce? I'd be glad if you could explain the injection for $2^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathcal{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{a}$ denotes a sequence of zeros and ones, i.e. $\mathbf{a} \in 2^\mathbb{N}$. Which part do you want to be explained, that is, is there something you have troubles understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this notation. if $f$ gets $a$, a binary sequence, how come it defined as $n \mapsto 2n...$? And what's the idea behind that?

Comment: @AnnieOK This means, that $\mathbf{b} = f(\mathbf{a})$ is also a sequence, and the $n$-th term of this sequence is defined as $\mathbf{b}_n = 2n+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathbf{a}_k$, for example $\mathbf{b}_2 = 4+\mathbf{a}_0+\mathbf{a}_1+\mathbf{a}_2$. Sequences can be understood as functions with domain $\mathbb{N}$, e.g. $\mathbf{a}_5$ is the value of $\mathbf{a}$ at $5$. So $f$ is a function that takes another function as an input (here it is the sequence $\mathbf{a}$) and outputs another function (sequence $\mathbf{b}$). Hence, notation in which $h(x) = x^2$ would be written as $h=x \mapsto x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bijection between strongly increasing sequences and positive sequences, by taking the difference between consecutive terms (ok, one should consider the first term apart in some way). Positive rational sequences are as many as
$$
  \mathbb N \to \mathbb N
$$
which are as many as $2^{\mathbb N}$ (*corrected*, I was wrong).

Comment: No, there are uncountably many postitive rational sequences, $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \ge 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$

Comment: corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A diagonalization argument can be used to show that the set of all strictly increasing sequences is uncountable, but this method is inherently limited.  If we let $\mathfrak{S}$ denote the set of such sequences, diagonalization can show that $$\vert\mathfrak{S}\vert>\aleph_{0},$$ i.e., that the set is uncountable. But without appealing to the continuum hypothesis, this does not allow us to conclude that $$\vert \mathfrak{S}\vert=2^{\aleph_{0}}.$$  To reash this conclusion, more work is needed.  (Or a different approach, such as that of @user2345215).

Anyway, if you really want to use diagonalization here, you need to do more work to ensure that the new sequence you generate is indeed strictly increasing.  Here's one approach:

We start with our presumed exhaustive enumeration of all strictly increasing sequences.  Let $\langle a_{n_k}\vert k<\omega\rangle$ be the $n$-th such sequence. Then define a new sequence $\langle b_{j}\vert j<\omega\rangle$ by:
$$b_{j}=j+\sum_{k=0}^{j}\vert a_{j_{k}}\vert$$ 
(where the vertical lines in this last formula denote absolute value, and not cardinality).